# Lumia Denim release date for Lumia Icon on Verizon

Tags: lumia-denim-update, lumia-icon

Does anyone know when Verizon will (finally) release Lumia Denim for the Icon?

I keep hearing it will be "soon", "early 2015", and "probably in January", but I can find no information as far as an actual release date.

EDIT: [Joe Belfiore has said](https://twitter.com/joebelfiore/status/561207799284113408) that by "early 2015" he meant January or February, less likely March.

Comment: If Verizon haven't said anything more specific, then we're not going to know any more either.

Comment: There is no additional public info about the release date and probably won't be until Denim is actually released on Verizon. You'll just have to wait!

Comment: If the info was available, you'd know - it would be public. There is no point in asking for release dates when there are none. The question should be removed :) ... as this happens with every update

Comment: Ok, I'll put something together.

Comment: @Drowin If Verizon have provided something more specific, then this question lacks research effort. If they haven't, then there's no factual information on which to base an answer. The first possibility warrants a downvote, the second a close vote. And no, not every answer on this site is a copy of existing information elsewhere.

Comment: @Drowin Fair enough, that's your opinion. I reserve the right to have mine, and vote accordingly. All part of the democratic process here at Stack Exchange :) By the way, I seem to recall that deleting a question will undo any reputation gains. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, unless Microsoft or Verizon publically state an exact date, ["Early 2015" is the best information we have](http://lumiaconversations.microsoft.com/2014/12/19/verizon-launch-lumia-denim-update-lumia-822-lumia-928-lumia-icon/).

Obviously, this can mean anywhere between January to March but these kinds of updates require a lot of co-operation between Microsoft and Verizon, and there's a lot of politics involved.

The delay in frustrating, I know, but at least the update *is* on it's way. I would suggest keeping an eye on...

1. [The official Microsoft software update page for Lumias.](https://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/availability-in-north-america/)
2. [Tech. news sites like Windows Central for any updates.](http://www.windowscentral.com/lumia-denim)

Comment: Or check on [Microsoft's site which is updated **as** versions become available](https://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/)

Comment: @RowlandShaw thanks, added the *obvious* option ;)

Comment: It's only obvious if you know where it's hidden ;)